# How to auto link a library in MinGW or GCC?

Tags: c, linker, mingw

When a custom library is used in the code, it requires `-l` linker parameter to use:

```
gcc myprogram.c -lmylibrary
```

Is there a way to convince MinGW linker to check header files and automatically find and link a library in `/lib` folder? Or is there a reason why it would be a bad idea?

Comment: Not possible with GCC directly, but I worked around with GNU Make and MSYS: https://github.com/tanzislam/cryptopals/blob/master/common_settings.mk#L77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The problem of looking at C source code and figuring out which libraries it uses is very hard. It feels kind of ["AI complete"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AI-complete) to me, which is why it's typically solved manually by the programmer pointing out the exact right libraries to satisfy the dependencies with.

Imagine for `mylibrary`, it's easy to imagine a system with both `mylibrary` 1.x and 2.x versions installed, and some calls are named exactly the same. Now try to imagine a computer program capable of deducing what you meant, which library to link with. It's not possible, since only the programmer knows.

The `pkg-config` tool helps with the mechanics of what each library requires in order to be used, but it's still up to you to tell it (via the module name argument(s)) *which* exact libraries to use.

Comment: And yet this behavior is functional with MSVC ...  
You say "artificial intelligence", I mention Microsoft, so strange ;-)

Comment: @JeanDavy Ah, a perfect example of IDEs hiding the details that a programmer should have learned thoroughly. MSVC and Boost (and many more) uses `#pragma` compiler directives to include libraries containing the used variable and function references. But, what if instead of adding dependencies to your IDE, you'd cobble up a bunch of libraries together and ask the compiler to do this, what would happen then? Sure if the name to be linked is unique it might be trivial but, what about different versions of the same library or two or more libraries containing the same name?

Comment: @JeanDavy And consider that this needs to be done for every undefined reference. That's a huge waste of time. But, I can't blame your for naively believing that the IDE is almighthy. It's a common misconception so I'll forgive you for it ;-)

Comment: Don't be so agressive ! My comment was only a comment, and beleive me or not I'm not naive. Anyway, I have very very good knowledge of "details that a programmer should have learned thoroughly", but I appreciate the automatic link, code browsing, automatic completion, and so on, and yet I am still able of doing arithmetic pointer. ... We left the cave for a long time.